# np.savetxt Não funciona para baixar arquivo CSV(Jupyter Notebook)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Desenvolvi um código para me ajudar a analisar dados de forma mais rápida do que vinha fazendo antes. Todo o desenvolvimento foi adaptado ao Jupyter Notebook usado no Google Chrome, isso porque a compania que trabalho não permite que eu instale qualquer terminal no meu notebook infelizmente.

A descrição do meu código é a seguinte:

Importar database do github

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

database_goodshipped = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CaiqueBarrreto/agroci/main/column2.csv")
```

Tratamento de dados por np.where

```
database_goodshipped['variavel_resposta'] = np.where(database_goodshipped['Goods Shipped'].str.contains('FLUTRIAFOL'), 'FLUTRIAFOL',
                                                     (np.where(database_goodshipped['Goods Shipped'].str.contains('CARBENDAZIM'), 'CARBENDAZIM', 'NID')))
```

Tentativa de transformar minha base tratada em um arquivo .csv

```
b = np.savetxt('myfile.csv', database_goodshipped, delimiter = ",", fmt = '%s')

a = open('myfile.csv', 'r')

print(a.read())
```

No caso, o erro que me é retornado é o seguinte:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Conforme descrevi, a intenção é baixar minha base em csv após tratá-la com o numpy; no caso, não entendi se este erro é porque o Jupyter Notebook na versão de browser não me permite fazer este tipo de comando ou se meu código está errado. De fato, nunca ouvi sobre donwloads feitos por este tipo de terminal, mas não custa tentar, né?! hahaha

Obrigado

Comment: Vai no arquivo `jupyter_notebook_config.py` e configure a entrada `NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit` ou então inicie o notebook com o parâmetro configurado `jupyter  --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=<coloque_aqui_o_valor_desejado>`

Comment: Augusto, obrigado pela informação. Mas como fazer isso na prática?

Comment: Na linha de comando digite `jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000000` ou outro valor

Comment: Augusto, tentei fazer conforme mas só da "invalid syntax".  Qualquer ajuste de memória que tento fazer está dando isso, na verdade. Será que pelo browser isso é permitido?

Comment: é no [google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/)?

Comment: na verdade era pelo Jupyter Lab. Tentei fazer pelo google colab como você sugeriu mas também dá o mesmo erro

Comment: @AugustoVasques, eu nao tenho grande necessidade de printar o arquivo final, só queria mesmo seguir com o download. Tem alguma sugestão, no caso?

Comment: É que lhe falei ou pela linha de comando(DOS, Powershell, Bash, ZSH... ou qualquer shell que use) inicializando o notebook com `jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000000` ou então vá na pasta onde está instalado o Jupyter Notebook e edite o arquivo *jupyter_notebook_config.py* e na linha onde tiver escrito `NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000` aumente o valor `NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000000`. Caso o seu notebook ainda não tenha o arquivo de configuração digite na linha de comando `jupyter notebook --generate-config`

Comment: Muito Obrigado!!! Deu certo aqui!